# How to convert .log file to .csv file

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

I need help with converting a log file into a .csv file. So far I have tried the following code but I cannot get the result that I want. In the input file until "test control", it is separated with "\t"

```
with open('input.log', 'r') as infile, open('output.csv', 'w') as outfile:
    stripped_lines = (line.strip() for line in infile)
    lines = (line.split(':') for line in stripped_lines if line)
    writer = csv.writer(outfile)
    writer.writerows(lines)
```

Input file:

```
12/15/21    09:16:56    test control: left: 23.2 right: 54.7 test input:85.3 distance:49.5 XY1:15.0 XY2:22.8 ZX1:25.0 ZX2:28.8 MN1:18.7 MN2:18.8 PN1:26.0 PN2:84.5 test speed: 23.2
04/30/21    11:20:38    test control: left: 36.2 right: 88.7 test input:87.4 distance:26.8 XY1:53.0 XY2:85.9 ZX1:95.0 ZX2:78.8 MN1:32.7 MN2:96.8 PN1:52.0 PN2:79.5 test speed: 23.2
```

Output:

```
12/15/21,09:16:56,23.2,54.7,85.3,49.5,15.0,22.8,25.0,28.8,18.7,18.8,26.0,84.5,23.2
04/30/21,11:20:38,36.2,88.7,87.4,26.8,53.0,85.9,95.0,78.8,32.7,96.8,52.0,79.5,23.2
```

Comment: and after `test control`? are those white space separating numbers and text until `test input:85.3`? I would use the tab to split the line string in a first iteration, then use `:` to split other entries, then remove white space ...

Comment: Even when I do that strings are still left in the .csv file, I only want the date, time, and float numbers. After test control, everything is separated by space

Comment: You still need to remove the strings from each line. Why do you expect `.split(':')` to do that for you?

Comment: I know `.split(':')` don't remove strings and I don't know how to remove them that's my problem. Maybe you can help me with that.

Comment: You know that you need to remove the elements at some indices of each `.split()` result. 
 Please do some research first and make an attempt at solving the problem yourself? [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261593/843953) Then ask a _specific_ question if your attempt is unsuccessful.

Comment: Before asking here, you need to be familiar with the rules of the site. This isn't a "write code for me" website. Please take the [tour], read [what's on-topic here](/help/on-topic), [ask], 
and the [question checklist](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260648/843953), 
and provide a [mre]. _Specific_ questions asking about a problem with your code are allowed. Your question shows no effort to solve the problem, so why would we assume you have tried anything?

Comment: Fair enough and thanks for the links. I will try to follow the rules of the community If I ask a question again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My first guess at a basic answer would be to use the `re` module to split on both `":"` and `" "`. Then I might just manually pick out the data points I needed.

```
import re
import csv

data_in = '''
12/15/21\t09:16:56\ttest control: left: 23.2 right: 54.7 test input:85.3 distance:49.5 XY1:15.0 XY2:22.8 ZX1:25.0 ZX2:28.8 MN1:18.7 MN2:18.8 PN1:26.0 PN2:84.5 test speed: 23.2
04/30/21\t11:20:38\ttest control: left: 36.2 right: 88.7 test input:87.4 distance:26.8 XY1:53.0 XY2:85.9 ZX1:95.0 ZX2:78.8 MN1:32.7 MN2:96.8 PN1:52.0 PN2:79.5 test speed: 23.2
'''

def parseRow(row):
    el = row.split("\t")
    sub_el = [item for item in re.split(":| ", el[2]) if item]
    return [
        el[0],
        el[1],
        float(sub_el[3]),
        float(sub_el[5]),
        float(sub_el[8]),
        float(sub_el[10]),
        float(sub_el[12]),
        float(sub_el[14]),
        float(sub_el[16]),
        float(sub_el[18]),
        float(sub_el[20]),
        float(sub_el[22]),
        float(sub_el[24]),
        float(sub_el[26]),
        float(sub_el[29]),
    ]

with open('output.csv', 'w', newline='') as outfile:
    writer = csv.writer(outfile)
    writer.writerows(parseRow(row) for row in data_in.split("\n") if row)
```

Given your data as I have interpreted it, this will produce a file that looks like:

```
12/15/21,09:16:56,23.2,54.7,85.3,49.5,15.0,22.8,25.0,28.8,18.7,18.8,26.0,84.5,23.2
04/30/21,11:20:38,36.2,88.7,87.4,26.8,53.0,85.9,95.0,78.8,32.7,96.8,52.0,79.5,23.2
```

Comment: Thanks for the help and I could implement it for my data file and it works as expected. For `el[2]`, do you split for colon and space together or you split whichever comes first?

Comment: the `re.split()` is a split on either item.